# How Save a int variable with SharedPreferences?

Tags: android, variables, save, int, sharedpreferences

Good day people,

I have a problem I would save whith `SharedPreference`  simple int value variable,
but I am having difficulty. 
I have a Flag-Variable "signum" that changes the value based on the made choice `ImageButton`, I would save this Flag-Value.                                                It's possible in one `Activity` use twice method `SharedPreferences`?
For me it's not important if the Flag-Value is a String or int variable, I need a easy way.
I think(but I'm not sure even of this) I'm in the wrong store in the code-line I'm in the code line : salvum2.putInt("semper2", 1 or 2); insert the right way
Thaks for all and for your help!

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private static final String MUTATIO = "semper";
private static final String MUTATIO2 = "semper2";
private ImageButton button;
int signum ;  //this is the variable that I want to save

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    choicheimagebutton();
    operation();
}


private void choicheimagebutton() {
    final SharedPreferences optio =         
            getSharedPreferences(MUTATIO, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    final SharedPreferences optio2 = 
            getSharedPreferences(MUTATIO2, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    button.setImageResource(optio.getInt(MUTATIO, R.drawable.default)); 

    button.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener(){

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {




final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
            dialog.setTitle("Titolo menù scelta");



            TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text);
            text.setText("Scegli l'icona");
            ImageView image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.image);
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

            dialog.show();

            Button dialogButtonLuce = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonLuceID);

            dialogButtonLuce.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {


                    button.setImageResource(R.drawable.lux);
                    signum = 1 ;
    SharedPreferences.Editor salvum = optio.edit();
    salvum.putInt("semper", R.drawable.lux);

         //Now I would save the flag-int-variable

    salvum.putInt("semper", 1);
    salvum.commit();
                    dialog.dismiss();

                }
            });


  Button dialogButtonGas = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonGasID);

    dialogButtonGas.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                button.setImageResource(R.drawable.gas);
                signum = 2;
                SharedPreferences.Editor salvum = optio.edit();
                salvum.putInt("semper", R.drawable.gas);
                salvum.commit();



                salvum.putInt("semper", 2);
                salvum.commit();
 dialog.dismiss();}});

 Button RESET = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogRipristinaID);
 RESET.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    optio.edit().clear().commit();

    dialog.dismiss();
    }});return true;}});}

private void operation() {
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (signum==1) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "I have a LUX", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
                }
            if (signum==2) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "I have GAS GAS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
            }
            else  {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "VACUUM", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
            }}});}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MUTATIO, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putInt("semper", R.drawable.lux );
editor.putInt("semper2", 1);
editor.commit();
```

Comment: Thanks Borad Hardik, I tried this way but don't save to .
Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I have just done, I changed with salvum2.putInt("semper2", 1 or 2) but still does not save( I think now It' better than before)

Comment: ok 1 thing y u dont create one file for all. remove this line.final SharedPreferences optio2 = 
            getSharedPreferences(MUTATIO2, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

Comment: have look my edited post. use like this for save all data in one file.

Comment: Borad, I don' know why, but, this code save my ImageButton-setteng but not save the flag value(semper).
When i clese and after open(reopen) my app(on emulator) the ImegeButton setting are saved, but the value signum no.thanks!

Comment: oh yes it should be string my mi-stack. semper should be like this "semper". sorry for that.

Comment: I don't know why, but dont' save!...damn :O

Comment: I have this in my code : salvum.putInt("semper2", 1);
           salvum.commit();
But i have to put : salvum.putInt("semper", 1);
        salvum.commit();   this??

Comment: I think I'm lost , sorry!

Comment: you dont have to commit 2 time. when you done with it let me know.

Comment: I put only one "commit", but dont' save .

Comment: Thanks Borad for your assistance!
I have found another solution, but your way is very good!, kind regards!

Comment: have look. i have edit your code and put some comment.

Answer (score 2):

If semper2 is a **STRING**, then this is wrong (all occurrences): `salvum2.putString("semper2", 2);`
it should be: `salvum2.putString("semper2", "2");`

If semper2 is an **INT**, then this is wrong (all occurrences): `salvum2.putString("semper2", 2);`
it should be: `salvum2.putInt("semper2", 2);`

Also note that you don't need to create an editor for each preference key you want to save: one is enough.
Commit the operations once, at the end of all your savings.

Comment: Vyger thanks for your clarification! (you've a reason!) but I I tried to change with right away (salvum2.putInt("semper2", 2);) , but does not save to (now edit my question). I always have the problem that I did not save the variable, thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

to save use this

```
private SharedPreferences prefs;
 prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(cntx);
 prefs.edit().putInt("userId", userId).commit();
prefsCommit();
```

and for getting use this

```
int userId = prefs.getInt("userId", 0);
```